# Cannot find published Nintex Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I published a Nintex Workflow to my site with NWAdmin:

```
NWAdmin.exe -o DeployWorkflow -workflowName "Approve Changes" -nwfFile ApproveChangesWF.nwf -siteUrl http://server/site -username username -password 1234 -domain xyz -overwrite
```

The result returned by the tool is:

```
Workflow Published.
```

Yet, I cannot find the workflow. 
When i go to `Site Actions` > `Nintex Workflow 2010` > `Manage site workflows`, I cannot see my workflow, that I just tried to add.
I'm also trying to get the workflow programatically, there are no workflows in the site.

```
SPWorkflowCollection workflowCollection = spWeb.Workflows;
workflowCollection.Count  //returns 0
```

How can I find this workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Manager (for both SharePoint 2007 and 2010) is a tool that shows pretty everything there is to know about your SharePoint farm.  If your workflow has indeed been deployed, you should be able to use this tool to find your workflow.  Word of caution:  this is a very powerful tool and every property for every object within your SharePoint farm is available to read, write, delete, etc...so, tread lightly.

http://spm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this. It could be that you have not activated the workflow. Only activated workflows can be associated with a list, library, content type, or site.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262348(v=office.14).aspx